# How to implement a horizontall gallery of images where the item to be centered by using Horizontal listview/Scrollview. Listview is more preferable?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, horizontallist

```
![enter code here][1]
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYZVG.jpg

From the above diagram it will be quite clear what I want. No matter how much scroll the user makes, after the scrolling stop,
the item which is fully seen or the item which has maximum visible area should be centered. Is this possible ? Also the first
item should be centered when scroll to initial area and last item too will be centered when scrolled to last position. 
As I have many items I would prefer a listview. Can you guys please help us?

Thanks
Timir

Answer (score 0):

Use view pager and implement it

or you can also use http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html

View flipper is another approach